# Why is scale_y_continuous not working here? No error message given

Tags: r, ggplot2

On my ggplot (see below), I was expecting `scale_y_continuous(breaks=(seq(0, 90, 10)))` to set y between 0 and 90 and spaced every 10.  Instead i get no y-axis or tick marks.

A google search turned up this which didnt deal with exactly my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709180/scale-y-continuous-not-working

using `ylim()` allows me to alter the scale, but doesnt allow me to change interval to every 10.

This is a dput of my data:

```
structure(list(dval = c(73.2, 76.7, 79.2, 74.9, 74.8, 76.8, 74.7, 
74, 77.2, 74.6, 74.2, 72.7), date = structure(c(17646, 17655, 
17675, 17681, 17701, 17729, 17743, 17751, 17757, 17778, 17793, 
17800), class = "Date")), row.names = c(43215L, 43224L, 43244L, 
43250L, 43270L, 43298L, 43312L, 43320L, 43326L, 43347L, 43362L, 
43369L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this is the code i used to try and plot:

```
ggplot(test, aes(date, dval)) +
    #scale_y_continuous() should be mking Y between 0 and 90 and spaced every 10, but isnt...
    #ylim() works but doesnt set default spacing of 10
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=(seq(0, 90, 10))) +
    #ylim(0, 80) +
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Comment: Did you try to adjust the `limits` argument of `scale_y_continuous` as well? I.e. `limits = c(0, 90)`

Comment: thanks markus. this worked and gives the result exactly as i wanted.  Cant accept your comment as an answer,

Comment: Don't worry. Accept Erich's answer when he edited it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comment from @markus sorted this for me.  Adding the `limits` argument to `scale_y_continuous` gave me the output i wanted:

```
ggplot(test, aes(date, dval)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=(seq(0, 90, 10)), limits = c(0, 90)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your dval values only lie between 72 and 79.x, so your breaks are outside iod the used data range.

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks=(seq(72,79,1)))
```

works.

Comment: It would be `... + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 90), breaks=(seq(0, 90, 10))) + ...`